# Using RegEx to extract string after second match?

Tags: regex

I have a script which is grabbing the URL of a Google Compute Backend. I want to use RegEx to extract a small part of it, but keep getting caught up in the first match:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/website-prod-1234/global/backendServices/website-prod-num-1111-backend
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/website-prod-1234/global/backendServices/website-prod-re-3724-backend
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/website-prod-1234/global/backendServices/website-prod-test-backend
```

In those examples, trying to extract the following parts:

```
num-1111
re-3724
test
```

This is my hack of an expression, but it gets caught up in the first occurrence of "website-prod-" and grabbing the whole half of the link. How can I make it start from the second part?

```
(?<=website-prod-).*(?=-backend)
```

Comment: have you tried to extract the last part/section of url with programming language?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use:

```
(?<=website-prod-)[^/]*(?=-backend)
```

Using `[^/]` instead of `.` prevents this from matching across directory delimiters.